# TSQL Make partitions "gaps and island"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create partitions. Suppose I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Pos INT UNIQUE, X INT)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (3, 2)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (5, 0)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (6, 0)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (9, 0)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (43, 9)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (53, 8)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (56, 0)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (81, 0)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (163, 1)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (9716, 0)
```

The query result should be this table with a column Y added, Y should be

IF X=0 : the previous value X<>0 (OR NULL, if not exists), ordered by Pos

IF X<>0 : X

Desired answer table looks like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyQuery as a function of MyTable 
ORDER BY Pos

Pos  X  Y
3    2  2
5    0  2
6    0  2
9    0  2
43   9  9
53   8  8
56   0  8
81   0  8
163  1  1
9716 0  1
```

Comment: This sounds like a gaps and island problem. What have you tried so far? Why didnt it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a type of *gaps-and-islands* problem.**

There are many solutions, here is one:

- Use a running conditional count to number the rows that we want to group together
- Use a partitioned conditional `MIN` to take the only value that we actually want, per group

```sql
WITH StartPoints AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(NULLIF(X, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY Pos)
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT
  Pos,
  X,
  Y = MIN(NULLIF(X, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId)
FROM StartPoints
ORDER BY Pos;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de2e4d0aecd9d89983018029087c511e)